# В QLabel выводится только последний символ, а нужно полностью всё предложение

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qtextbrowser

Цикл `for` в `QLabel` выводит только последний символ, а нужно полностью всё предложение. Зарание спасибо за помощь.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Encryption machine!")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 450, 330)
        self.label_1.setFixedWidth(261)
        self.label_1.setFixedHeight(31)
        #Надпись "Текст у шифр"
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setText("Введіть речення, слово, букву")
        self.label_1.move(120, 20)
        self.label_1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        #ввод тексту
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.line_edit.move(20, 70)
        self.line_edit.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        #створення кнопки "Текст у шифр"
        self.btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_1.setText("Текст у шифр")
        self.btn_1.move(20, 160)
        self.btn_1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.d_text_btn_1)
        #створення перекладу (без настройок) для btn_1
        self.text_btn_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_btn_1.move(20, 200)

    def d_text_btn_1(self):
        #заносим значення line_edit у переменую path
        path = self.line_edit.toPlainText()
        slovnuk_shufry = {
            "а":"е", 
            "б":"н",
            "в":"б",
            "г":"р",
            "д":"и",
            "е":"у",
            "є":"в",
            "ж":"ї",
            "з":"ч",
            "и":"г",
            "ї":"о",
            "й":"є",
            "к":"л",
            "л":"д",
            "м":"щ",
            "н":"й",
            "о":"ю",
            "п":"а",
            "р":"с",
            "с":"м",
            "т":"я",
            "у":"п",
            "ф":"ж",
            "х":"ц",
            "ц":"х",
            "ч":"к", 
            "ш":"т",
            "щ":"ш",
            "ь":"з",
            "ю":"ь",
            "я":"ф"}
        for char in path:
            prin = slovnuk_shufry[char]
        #настройка відповіді
        self.text_btn_1.setText(prin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wind_1 = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wind_2 = Window()
    wind_2.show()
    sys.exit(wind_1.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                    # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                   # !!! +++
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Шифровальная машина!")
        self.resize(700, 300)
        
        self.slovnuk_shufry = {
            "а": "е", 
            "б": "н",
            "в": "б",
            "г": "р",
            "д": "и",
            "е": "у",
            "є": "в",
            "ж": "ї",
            "з": "ч",
            "и": "г",
            "ї": "о",
            "й": "є",
            "к": "л",
            "л": "д",
            "м": "щ",
            "н": "й",
            "о": "ю",
            "п": "а",
            "р": "с",
            "с": "м",
            "т": "я",
            "у": "п",
            "ф": "ж",
            "х": "ц",
            "ц": "х",
            "ч": "к", 
            "ш": "т",
            "щ": "ш",
            "ь": "з",
            "ю": "ь",
            "я": "ф",
        }

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Введите предложение, слово, букву: ")

        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("Шифровать текст")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.encrypt_text)

        self.encrypted_text = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()              # ! QTextBrowser
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)     # !!! +++
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, 2, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(QLabel('Зашифрованный текст: '), 3, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.encrypted_text, 3, 2, 1, 2)
        
    def encrypt_text(self):
        text = self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        
        self.encrypted_text.clear()                               # +++ 
        for char in text:
            prin = self.slovnuk_shufry.get(char)                  # +++ .get(char) 
            if not prin:                                          # +++
                prin = char                                       # +++

            self.encrypted_text.insertPlainText(prin)             # !!! +++

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))       # +++
    
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спросите, если что-то не понятно.